# stooped banner floating in the wind

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When a banner is floating in the wind, its mast slanted, like in the midst of a battlefield after a battle, can one say "A stooped banner was floating in the wind"?  I would like to avoid "slanted". Thanks

Comment: 'A banner on a sloping pole ....'

Comment: I think *stooped* is a fine choice describing the weariness of the banner after the struggle.

Comment: It sounds poetic. I like it. In terms of accuracy, it is not the banner that is stooping (because it is in fact floating), it is the mast.

Comment: A sagging banner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions of *stooped* in Lexico and M-W don't support your use of *stooped* to describe a banner floating in the wind from a slanted mast. Perhaps **angled** would work. From Lexico:

> **[angled](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/angled)**: Placed or inclined at an angle to something else.

Your example:

> "an **angled** banner floating in the wind"

**Angled** works if you think of the banner and the mast as a single entity, in which case the angle is that between the mast and vertical. It gets the image across and sounds poetic.